# I accidentally used git clone twice

Tags: git, command-line, bitbucket

Originally, I had cloned a repo. The repo contains various R scripts that me and my colleagues have worked on.

Ideally, scripts where located in the following file path (example names used):

**Fruits**(The main folder) ->

- Apple
- **Blueberry** ->

  ```
  * Pie

  * Chocolate (The folder w/ scripts)

  * Milkshake
  ```
- Pear
- Strawberry

Today I was trying to add and push a new script that I had created via command line, but it kept showing as not listed as one of the changes I've made. I was also trying to receive the changes made by my peer with `git add origin main`, but the changes weren't showing up in the chocolates folder.

I decided to take a further look, and apparently I had created a git clone within a git clone. So now it looks like

**Fruits**(The main folder) ->

- Apple
- Blueberry
- **Fruits** ->

  ```
  * Apple

  * Blueberry

  * Pear

  * Strawberry
  ```
- Pear
- Strawberry

Now I'm trying to figure out how to put everything into that original Blueberry -> Chocolate folder. To re-iterate, the changes that my colleague made are in that ideal folder, while the changes that I've made and want to share are in that accidentally cloned sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are dealing with only a single branch,

1. Move the child folder out of the parent.  For example, in the parent,

   ```
   mv ./Fruits ../Fruits2
   ```

   That particular variation will change the child folder to a sibling folder.  Subsequent steps assume that choice of new location and name; adjust as necessary if you choose different ones.
2. In both `Fruits` and `Fruits2`, commit all uncommitted changes that you want to keep.
3. In `Fruits`, perform a `git pull ../Fruits2` to obtain the changes and revision history from `Fruits2`.
4. If any merging is needed then perform that (in `Fruits/`) and commit the result.
5. Satisfy yourself that `Fruits` is up to date with all changes from both folders.
6. Delete `Fruits2`.